# In the classification of three classes, accuracy does not improve by 46% under any circumstances

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, classification

i have a network for classify data into 3 class.data are 13760 Two-dimensional array with 19 row and 1280 column and data type is float(In fact, my data is eeg). first trained network by convolution autoencoder and save model.h5 then get encoder output and re-train in multi layer and finally use for classification. classification accuracy is always 0.46. i change lots of parameters,change learning rate,loss function,optimizer,deep of network,use different layer,normalize data,....but the accuracy didn't improve .even convert conv1d to con2d but result is same. I don't know what else to do?
train code is:

```
input_img = Input(shape=(24320,1))  #24320=19*1280 

x = Conv1D(16, 4, activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv1')(input_img)
x = BatchNormalization()(x) 
x = Conv1D(16, 4, activation='relu',padding='same', name='conffv2')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = MaxPooling1D(4, padding='same', name='max1')(x)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)


x = Conv1D(32, 4, activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv2')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x) 
x = Conv1D(32, 4, activation='relu', padding='same', name='cofnvk2')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = MaxPooling1D(4, padding='same', name='max2')(x)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)

x = Conv1D(64, 4, activation='relu', padding='same', name='convk2')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Conv1D(64, 4, activation='relu',padding='same')(x)
x = Conv1D(64, 4, activation='relu',padding='same')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = MaxPooling1D(4, padding='same', name='maxgg2')(x)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)

x = Conv1D(128, 4, activation='relu', padding='same', name='ufqq')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Conv1D(128, 4, activation='relu', padding='same', name='con3')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
encoded = MaxPooling1D(4, padding='same', name='max3')(x)


x = Conv1D(128, 4, activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv4')(encoded)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Conv1D(128, 4, activation='relu', padding='same', name='slgg')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x) 
x = UpSampling1D(4, name='up1')(x) 
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)

x = Conv1D(64, 4, activation='relu', padding='same', name='convjj5')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Conv1D(64, 4, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = Conv1D(64, 4, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = UpSampling1D(4, name='upddd2')(x)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)


x = Conv1D(32, 4, activation='relu', padding='same', name='rr')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Conv1D(32, 4, activation='relu',padding='same', name='conv5')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = UpSampling1D(4, name='up2')(x)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)


x = Conv1D(16, 4, activation='relu', padding='same', name='conegv6')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Conv1D(16, 4, activation='relu',padding='same',name='conv6')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = UpSampling1D(4,name='upq3')(x)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x) 
decoded = Conv1D(1, 4, activation='sigmoid', padding='same', name='conv7')(x)
autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)


autoencoder.compile(SGD(lr=0.0001, nesterov=True), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
autoencoder.summary()          




arrayofdata=[] 
inputdata = '/content/Cleaned'
countfile = len([name for name in os.listdir(inputdata) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(inputdata, name))])
files = os.listdir(inputdata)
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(inputdata, '*.mat')):
    mat = sio.loadmat(filename, squeeze_me=True, struct_as_record=False)
    inputdata = mat['Data']
    inputdata_ = np.hsplit(inputdata, [1280])
    inputdata = inputdata_[0]        
    arrayofdata.append(inputdata.tolist())
    arrayofdata_=arrayofdata


arrayofdata_ = np.array(arrayofdata_)
labels = inputdata_[1]
x_train=arrayofdata_
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0],x_train.shape[1]*x_train.shape[2],1))

from sklearn.preprocessing import Normalizer

amin=min(x_train.flatten())
amax=max(x_train.flatten())

for i, val in enumerate(x_train):    
x_train[i] = (val-amin) / (amax-amin)



cp = ModelCheckpoint(filepath="/content/model.h5",
                                   save_best_only=True,
                                   verbose=1)

tb = TensorBoard(log_dir='/content/logs',
                    histogram_freq=0,
                    write_graph=True,
                    write_images=True)


history = autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
                     epochs= 100,
                     batch_size=32,
                   shuffle=False,
                 verbose=0,validation_split=0.2,
                     validation_data=(x_train, x_train),
                     callbacks=[cp, tb])




decoded_imgs = autoencoder.predict(x_train)
print(decoded_imgs.shape)

score = autoencoder.evaluate(x_train, x_train)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])        
autoencoder.save_weights("/content/model.h5")
```

Below is the code for the classification section: first load above model and then train encoder and classify

```
    autoencoder.load_weights("/content/model.h5")
    print("Loaded Model from disk")

    weights_list = autoencoder.get_weights()

    autoencoder.layers.pop()
    autoencoder.layers.pop()
    autoencoder.layers.pop()
    autoencoder.layers.pop()
    autoencoder.layers.pop()
    autoencoder.layers.pop()
    autoencoder.layers.pop()
    autoencoder.layers.pop()
    autoencoder.layers.pop()
    autoencoder.layers.pop()
    autoencoder.layers.pop()



    autoencoder.compile(Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999,epsilon=None,decay=0.0,  amsgrad=False), loss='categorical_crossentropy')


    autoencoder.summary()
    #classification using encoded output


    y=Conv1D(128, 4, activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
    y=Conv1D(128,4,padding='same',activation='relu')(y)
    y=BatchNormalization()(y)
    y = MaxPooling1D(2, name='max722')(y)    
    y=Dropout(0.25)(y)

    y=Conv1D(64, 4, activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv3238')(y)
    y=Conv1D(64,4,padding='same',activation='relu')(y)
    y=BatchNormalization()(y)
    y = MaxPooling1D(2, name='max788')(y)    
    y=Dropout(0.25)(y)

    y=Conv1D(32, 4, activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv8')(y)
    y=Conv1D(32,4,padding='same',activation='relu')(y)
    y=BatchNormalization()(y)
    y = MaxPooling1D(2, name='max7')(y)    
    y=Dropout(0.25)(y) 

    y = Conv1D(16, 4, padding='same', activation='relu', name = 'conv9')(y)
    y = Conv1D(16, 4, padding='same',activation='relu')(y)
    y = BatchNormalization()(y)
    y = MaxPooling1D(2, name='max8')(y)
    y = Dropout(0.25)(y)  

    y = Conv1D(8, 4, padding='same', activation='relu')(y)
    y = Conv1D(8, 4, padding='same',activation='relu')(y)
    y = BatchNormalization()(y)
    y = MaxPooling1D(2)(y)
    y = Dropout(0.25)(y) 

    y=Flatten()(y)

    y = Dense(256,  activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01),
    activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.01))(y)

    y = Dropout(0,5)(y)     
    y1 = Dense(3, activation='softmax',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01),
    activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.01))(y)     
    classifier= Model(inputs=autoencoder.input, outputs=y1)
    classifier.summary()

    arrayofdata=[] 
    inputdata = '/content/Cleaned'
    countfile = len([name for name in os.listdir(inputdata) if   os.path.isfile(os.path.join(inputdata, name))])
    files = os.listdir(inputdata)
    for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(inputdata, '*.mat')):
    mat = sio.loadmat(filename, squeeze_me=True, struct_as_record=False)     
    inputdata = mat['Data']
    inputdata_ = np.hsplit(inputdata, [1280])
    inputdata = inputdata_[0]        
    arrayofdata.append(inputdata.tolist())
    arrayofdata_=arrayofdata     
    arrayofdata_ = np.array(arrayofdata_)



    arrayoflable=[] 
    inputdata1 = '/content/Target'
    countfile2 = len([name for name in os.listdir(inputdata1) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(inputdata1, name))])
    files1 = os.listdir(inputdata1)
    for filename1 in glob.glob(os.path.join(inputdata1, '*.mat')):

    mat1 = sio.loadmat(filename1, squeeze_me=True, struct_as_record=False)     
    inputdata1 = mat1['Data']
    inputdata1 = inputdata1[0]
    arrayoflable.append(inputdata1.tolist())
    arrayoflable_=arrayoflable



    labels = np.array(arrayoflable_)    
    one_hot_labels = to_categorical(labels, num_classes=3)    
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(arrayofdata_,
                                              one_hot_labels,
                                              test_size=0.33,
                                              random_state=42)


    x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255
    x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255
    x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0],x_train.shape[1]*x_train.shape[2],1))
    x_test= np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0],x_test.shape[1]*x_test.shape[2],1))


    amin=min(x_train.flatten())
    amax=max(x_train.flatten())

    for i, val in enumerate(x_train):   
    x_train[i] = (val-amin) / (amax-amin)

    amintest=min(x_test.flatten())
    amaxtest=max(x_test.flatten())

    for i, val in enumerate(x_test):  
      x_test[i] = (val-amaxtest) / (amaxtest-amintest) 



    from sklearn.utils import compute_class_weight
    w = compute_class_weight('balanced', np.unique(labels), labels)
    weights = {
    np.unique(labels)[0] : w[0], 
    np.unique(labels)[1] : w[1],
    np.unique(labels)[2] : w[2] }


    classifier.compile(SGD(lr=0.001),loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])

     history= classifier.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=5,batch_size=16,
                    shuffle=True,  
                    verbose=0,class_weight=weights,                         
                    validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
                    callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir='/content/tmp/autoencoder')])


    print('val_loss:',mean(history.history['val_loss']))
    print('loss:',mean(history.history['loss']))         
    print('val_categorical_accuracy:',mean(history.history['val_binary_accuracy'])) 
    print('categorical_accuracy:',mean(history.history['binary_accuracy']))
```

Comment: Try printing the classification outputs to see if its predicting the same class or if there is a pattern.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: - Why are you concataining all you rows in one vector? it would be more appropriate if you keep the intial shape of the data
 - Why are you using an autencoder architecture for a classification task ?  
 - You should change your loss function, why are using binary crossentropy  in the first part, you should more use MSE, unless you rimages are binary?

Comment: for classification i use encoded output. autoencoder is for train.I also used MSE but it didn't work.even i change conv1d to conv2d and other setting but it didn't work.